# ZigZags line draw in android is drawing points

Tags: android, canvas, paint

**While drawing zigzag line this is drawing points instead of lines attached image[image]**

```
switch (selected_drawing_option) 
{
```

// this code is for drawing straight line and working well

```
**case OPTION_DRAW_LINE:**
currentShape = new LineShape(new Paint(paint), x, y, x + 10, y);
listOfShapesToBeDrawn.add(currentShape);
break;


// this code is for drawing circle and working well    

    **case OPTION_DRAW_CIRCLE:**
        currentShape = new CircleShape(new Paint(paint), x, y, 5);
        listOfShapesToBeDrawn.add(currentShape);
        break;

    **case OPTION_DRAW_RECTANGLE:**
    // this code is for drawing rectangle and working well
    currentShape = new RectangleShape(new Paint(paint), x, y,x + 5, y + 5);
    listOfShapesToBeDrawn.add(currentShape);
    break;

    **case OPTION_DRAW_FREESTYLE:**
    //Here is bug this code should draw freestyle line(Similar to signature) but drawing pixels 
    if (path != null) {
        }
    pp = new PathPaint();
    path.moveTo(x, y);
    path.lineTo(x, y);

    currentShape = new FreestyleShape(new Paint(paint), x, y);
    pp.setPathPaint(path, getPaint());
    listOfShapesToBeDrawn.add(currentShape);
    break;
```

Comment: Where is your paint, path and what is FreestyleShape?

Comment: FreeStyle shape is class that is drawing line

Comment: Here is code for same http://pastebin.com/NdVcyHiA

Comment: There might be some flaw in calculating the position x and y. And I don't know what is the base class DrawingShape is.